# Dropdown select start spinner in Angular 6

Tags: drop-down-menu, angular-material, spinner, angular6

I have the following code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6wtyrh

I have tried to get a spinner to popup to notify the user that data is loading.  I am not having much luck.  I have loaded a lot of data in my example, so that one can see how long it takes for the data to populate the fields.  All you have to do is click on a selection (more likely the bottom one) and see that it takes some time until the page responds.  What can be done to kickoff the spinner.

The spinner's triggered and hidden by an *ngIf.  I have tried triggering the starter in the `<mat-select>` and even the `<mat-option>` elements.

```
<mat-select panelClass='element-selection-width' #elementSelection='ngModel' #selectDropdown [ngModel]='elementSelectionListngModel' placeholder='Select an Existing Element ({{elementSelectionList.length}})' (selectionChange)='startCog()'   (ngModelChange)='onChange($event)'>
```

or

```
<mat-option *ngFor='let element of elementSelectionList' [value]='element.id'  (click)='startCog()'>
```

It does not seem to go until the data has already loaded into the fields, and it does not even shutoff the cogs, after the data has been loaded into the fields with the statement:

```
this.loading = false; // used to hide cogs
```

in the `onChange()` method that has been written to load the data.

Any help would be appreciated in getting the code to let the user know that their click has been registered, by showing the cogs, and then hiding the cogs, once the data has been loaded.

Any Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works, its just that **this.loading = false** is being set before the UI calls **startCog()**.

- If you put a console log above **this.loading = false** and watch the console when you select the drop-down you will see the timing issue I am referring to.

If you wrap your **this.loading = false** in a setTimeout for 2 seconds the cogs will disappear... typically you would set this false on a response from an API call or some other mechanism, in which case this setTimeout will not be necessary and is only simulating the delay of the API.

```
console.log('setting false')
setTimeout(()=>this.loading = false,2000);
```

**Update:**

After playing around with your stackblitz example some more, you definitely are experiencing browser blocking because of this ngFor loop when selecting **From Data 01 To Another Data Entry**

```
<div *ngFor='let panelLayout of sourceDestinationParametersValuesData'>
```

- When blocking like this occurs its like the browser just locks and
  does nothing else until it iterates through the large subset of data
  in order to render the view.
- This ultimately is why your cogs are not starting like they should.
- You will probably need to think about ways to either split this data into smaller subsets, or evaluate the design to determine if it can be completely moved to a different part of the workflow.
- You are expecting the browser to do too much, and need to find a way to spread the workload out.

**Update2:**
Here is a solution I use in my projects to trick the DOM into only iterating over those large subsets of data when the user clicks the element.

- This makes the spinner work how you want it to... however
- This now slows down the expanding of the mat-expansion-panel which is where the issue truly is.

HTML code change

```
<div *ngFor='let panelLayout of sourceDestinationParametersValuesData; let i = index'>
            <mat-expansion-panel #i id='panelLayout.panelId' class='expansionPanel'>
              <mat-expansion-panel-header class='expansionHeader'>
                {{panelLayout.title}}
              </mat-expansion-panel-header>
              <div *ngIf="i.expanded" class='expansion-panel-content'>
```

Comment: Please see revised answer

Comment: Thank you very much.  I think I understand your logic.  First off, maybe you can point this out to me.  Why is `startCog` being called after `onChange`'s `this.loading = false`?  Then second, I think I get how the `i.expanded` call works with the `*ngIf`, but it does still take a long time to load the panel, as you said, and then the user's going to wonder why the panel is not expanding instantly.  Eventually, there will be a call to a DB, so, the browser won't be dealing with the data I loaded, I think.  Is there a way to make a `stopCog()` not fire until the panel has expanded?

Comment: I suspect that onChange is called from ngModelChange which starts the "blocking" because it is the first thing to happen, it isn't until the browser is done with all of the OnChange logic and the loops that the view starts to render, which then allows the selectionChange event to fire. Using (afterExpand)="stopCog()" on the mat-expansion-panel should work.